# Is there an option equivalent to HTML datalist tag in materialize css?

Tags: materialize

I am looking for a dropwdown with an option to enter any string for search in materialize css framework. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete:

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col s12">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s12">
         <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
         <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
         <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html

Comment: I'll add that for more recent versions of materialize, you may want to use [minLength : 0 option](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html#options) to show options without user having to type first